# Let $a$ and $n$ be integers with $n>0$.
Show that the additive order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$.

Tags: group-theory, ordered-groups

Let $a$ and $n$ be integers with $n>0$.
Show that the additive order of $a$ modulo $n$ is $\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$.

**attempt:**
Let $a$ and $n$ be integers with $n>0$.
Let $m=\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$.
Then,
\begin{equation*}
ma = \left(\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}\right)a =
n\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,n)}\right)
\equiv 0 \pmod{n}.
\end{equation*}
Since $d=\gcd(a,n)$ is the greatest positive integer such that $d\mid a$ and $d \mid n$, then $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $n \mid ma$.

Hence, $m$ is the additive order of $a$ modulo $n$.

Am I true?

Comment: See this duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928569/for-the-additive-group-modulo-n-whats-the-proof-that-the-order-of-each-eleme?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For the additive group modulo $n$, what's the proof that the order of each element is given by $\frac{|G|}{\text{ GCD}(x,|G|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928569/for-the-additive-group-modulo-n-whats-the-proof-that-the-order-of-each-eleme)

Comment: @NoahSolomon not yet...

Answer (score 2):

A bit more constructively. The order of $\bar a \in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is by definition the least positive integer, say $o(\bar a)$, such that $o(\bar a)\bar a=\bar 0$. But, $o(\bar a)\bar a=\overline{o(\bar a)a}$, and hence:

\begin{alignat}{1}
o(\bar a)\bar a=\bar 0 &\iff \overline{o(\bar a)a}=\bar 0 \\
&\iff o(\bar a)a \equiv 0 \pmod n \\
&\iff o(\bar a)a=mn
\end{alignat}

for some $m\in \Bbb Z$. Therefore, the order of $\bar a$ is the *least* positive *integer* of the form $n/(a/m)$, and it is then gotten when the denominator is the *greatest* divisor of $a$ which is also divisor of $n$, namely:

$$o(\bar a)=\frac{n}{\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)}$$

Comment: It means that $\frac{a}{m}$ is not necessarily equal to the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $n$, isn't it?

Comment: It is because the word "when ... " in your statement above, right?

Comment: I mean, statement "word ... " above.

Comment: @user795084, yes right; a non-greatest common divisor of $a$ and $n$ would give a multiple of the sought order.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks yow!

Answer (score 2):

The additive order of $a$ modulo $n$ is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $ma \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

Now, $ma = kn$ for some integer $k$.
Then, $m = \frac{kn}{a}$.

Let $\gcd(a,n) = d$. Then,
$m = k\frac{\frac{n}{d}}{\frac{a}{d}}$.

Since $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ are relative prime, then $\frac{a}{d} \mid k$. Hence, the order of $a$ is a multiple of
$\frac{n}{d}$. Since the order must be minimum, then the order of $a$ is
$\frac{n}{d}$.

Is the approach above true?